# Как сделать input недоступным для ввода?

Tags: javascript, css

Как сделать `input` недоступным для ввода пользователя, через `CSS` и `JavaScript`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery:

```
 $("input[name=name_of_input]").attr("readonly",true);
```

Comment: Без `jquery`. Надо получить элемент, и установить его атрибут. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Есть такой аттрибут: `"disabled"`

```
$("#editor").attr("disabled", true)
```

Comment: при disabled он не прийдет в реквесте

Comment: Ну, собственно да.